# No access to models in admin panel with DEBUG=False

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I've some problem with access to models defined in my Django application. When I have in settings.py:

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
```

then everything works correctly. If I set DEBUG = False, then in admin panel I see section with my application name, and registered models, but the name of model isn't clickable (link) as normal. Also I don't see icon to add/edit objects to my registered models. Other standard applications as Auth, Flatpages looks ok. When I back set DEBUG = True, then everything works ok.
Has anyone any idea what could be a reason of this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I've found reason of my problems. It was caused by registering my models in admin panel from files with models definitions. When I moved all my registrations to one external file admin.py, then everything works correctly.

Comment: Thanks this put me on the right track. For me, I had a models.py file that imported all of my sub-apps. I created another file alongside models.py, called admin.py, and imported all of my sub-app admin files from here.

Comment: Thank you very much, really, thank you for your solution.
I'm keeping an old application with Django 1.3.
When I set up DEBUG = False Django admin stopped working (the links to the various admin pages returned 404). I searched for hours in the documentation but I could not understand why this behavior. In the end, reading your answer, I realized what was wrong: the models were registered in models.py. Now I have moved all the calls to admin.site.register() in the admin.py (file created on purpose, it was not present in the project folder) and everything works.
Thank you very much.