# Django Admin Pages making my models unclickable

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

For some reason, my /admin page has made the models I defined un-editable. This is on my deployed server using apache and postgres. I'm logged in as a superuser and the is showing the links like this:

[image: whhyyyy]

If I look at the same code locally in the development server connected to postgres, it looks like this:

[image]

Any idea what could be causing this?

** Update **

So it's not always blocked. I logged in today and I had access for a few actions (I cleaned some bogus email requests from my DB) but then after deleting some rows it got back to the read-only state.

Still no idea what's causing it.

home.models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.utils import timezone

class EmailRequest(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())


class EmailRequestForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
```

home.admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from home.models import EmailRequest

class EmailRequestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'created_date')

admin.site.register(EmailRequest, EmailRequestAdmin)
```

Comment: Could it be a role setting perhaps? Since this settings is stored in the database.

Comment: Check that you are really have superuser status.

Comment: @sneawo yah I do. The thing that's weird is that it's sporadic, so some times I do have access and then it just disappears.

Comment: @RickardZachrisson I don't think it's the role settings, I'm superuser and just as part of poking around testing I added all the user permissions to my user (which should be redundant since I'm superuser).

Comment: @Mortoc still, this is computers... :) If the code base is identical it should either lay in database or python module versions. I would try two things: 1. Play around with database dumps. 2. Set up your project in a virtual machine. That way you can try out both module versions as well as database data. Or perhaps virtualenv will suffice.

Comment: You might be having intermittent database query errors.  The template processor hides most errors and simply returns null.  The part that determines if a link is there or not in the admin section above is a fairly simple permissions query.   Have you added your own object permissions to that object?  Not that would work/not work randomly.

Comment: @RobOsborne I haven't touched object permissions. I'll add my model and admin code for the above to see if that helps.

Comment: What django version are you using ?

Comment: The Django Version is 1.4.3-1 | The server is the Amazon Web Services Bitnami Django Stack: https://aws.amazon.com/amis/bitnami-django-stack-1-4-3-1-64-bit-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: Is your development server configured for WSGI daemon mode, but your production server maybe not?

Comment: Are you using [admin.autodiscover()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a direct answer to your problem, but I do have a few personal insights.  First of all, using the Bitnami Django stack is probably a problem.  I have used it a couple of times, and I never will again.  The setup is definitely NOT ideal, and there is way too little documentation available for it to make your life any easier (wait, wasn't that the whole point of using a Bitnami stack?).

I would start looking through your logs (apache error log and postgres error logs specifically), I bet there is something in there that will point you in the correct direction.

I am sure you are running your development server from your local machine which is setup completely differently from the Bitnami stack.  The better solution would be to install everything yourself on a barebones Ubuntu server.  Then you will have much more familiarity with the setup.

THE BEST THING you can do, is go learn to use [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/).  This will help you to maintain a local virtual machine instance, which is identical to your EC2 box.  You will log into it using ssh just like the EC2 box, and you will be using it externally, just like the EC2 box.  The closer you can get your development environment to your production environment, the easier debugging problems like this will be.

Hope that didn't make your life more difficult (seriously, if you get Vagrant running, your life will become MUCH easier)

Comment: Thanks for that, I appreciate it. Yes, I did use bitnami to try to make my life easier, but it looks like I'm doing a custom configuration by hand.

Comment: honestly, you will be happier after the fact, just document every step of how you setup everything, then you can reproduce it easily, by hand.... or in a bootstrap script... (ahem)

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer. I never figured it out specifically, but ditching the bitnami stack cleaned it up.

Answer (score 0):

See the following solution:
[No access to models in admin panel with DEBUG=False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780740/no-access-to-models-in-admin-panel-with-debug-false)

quote:

> OK, I've found reason of my problems. It was caused by registering my
>   models in admin panel from files with models definitions. When I moved
>   all my registrations to one external file admin.py, then everything
>   works correctly.

Comment: This doesn't answer my problem though. I read that issue while initially trying to debug this, but my problem is different. It makes no difference whether DEBUG is True or False in my case. Additionally, I already have my files structured with home.admin.py and home.models.py as they suggest.